# How many balls are used in a typical World Cup game?

Tags: football, equipment, world-cup

I've noticed that often after a ball goes out a different ball is used. Also I don't know if the same ball will be used for both halves (plus extra time). So how many balls are used during a typical FIFA World Cup 2014 game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FIFA's laws continue to state that `'The ball may not be changed during the match without the authority of the referee.'` However as you may have seen during the FIFA World Cup as well as other competitions, many associations have accepted the Multiball system. So it is hard to find a documented maximum number or an average number of balls per match. But as per the [wikipedia entry on the Multiball system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiball_system), generally about a maximum of 7 balls are used per game.

Also, I read [here](http://2014.7msport.com/video/content/14528.shtml) that Adidas manufactured and tested 20 balls for the Final World Cup game between Germany and Argentina.

A lot of people are against this system because home teams, specially in England use it to their advantage and ask the local ball boys to waste time during away throw-ins, etc.

Comment: @gdrt94 - are you suggesting the quote is wrong, or it is missing the correct reference? I looked in Law 2, and the quoted text is contained there, word for word. The reason there is no link is because in 2014, FIFA published the Laws as a cumbersome PDF. Since this user hasn't been seen on the site for ~18 months, if you want the answer updated to reference the current laws, you're probably best off doing it yourself.

Comment: The quoted text is the same as in the rule, but it is used in incorrect place. *'The ball may not be changed during the match without the authority of the referee'* applies to **defect** balls only, as it is written under *'Replacement of a defective ball section'*. E.g. a player doesn't need the authority of the referee when he changes a ball during throw-in.

Answer (score 4):

[This article from The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/football/2014/jul/23/what-happens-to-world-cup-balls) says that:

> In total 3,240 balls were used throughout the tournament *(2014 FIFA
>   World Cup Brazil)*, **20** for each match

Generally, **FIFA Laws of the Game** [Law 02 - The Ball: 3. Additional balls](http://theifab.com/laws/the-ball/chapters/additional-balls) only states that:

> Additional balls which meet the requirements of Law 2 *(technical requirements)* may be placed
>   around the field of play and their use is under the referee’s control.

*Side note:*

The accepted answer incorrectly references to [Law 02 - The Ball: 2. Replacement of a **defective** ball.](http://theifab.com/laws/the-ball/chapters/replacement-of-a-defective-ball)

> The ball may not be changed during the match without the referee’s
>   permission.

The following statement applies only to **defective** balls, as it is written under *"Replacement of a defective ball section"*, and it doesn't apply to **any** balls.

E.g. if suddenly a player realizes that the ball he was playing with is defect, he has to notify the referee first and then change the ball, but if he changes a normal ball during throw-in, there's no need to notify the referee.

Comment: You should probably [refer to the correct IFAB laws](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/664/) yourself, if being critical of others.

Comment: I was (before the edit) and I am referring to correct IFAB rules.